# python collecting data from dataframe at specific row location

Tags: python, pandas

I am importing a data set with about 200 columns with unique column names into pandas dataframe using read_csv.

```
Data.columns
Index([u'SAVERECORDER', u'SAVECHANNEL', u'STARTTIME', u'INT001', u'INT002',
       u'INT003', u'INT004', u'INT005', u'INT006', u'INT007',
       ...
       u'INT092', u'INT093', u'INT094', u'INT095', u'INT096', u'INT097',
       u'INT098', u'INT099', u'INT100', u'LSTIME'],
      dtype='object', length=104)
```

I want to extract 100th row from each of the columns INT001 through INT099. Had it been few columns I would have done it manually but I don't have a clue as to how to extract certain row number from all and store in a numpy array. All columns INT001 through INT099 contain temperature values as double.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

data:

```
In [24]: df
Out[24]:
   a  b  c  INT001  INT002  INT003
0  8  1  1       4       2       6
1  2  9  2       5       3       6
2  4  2  9       3       5       2
3  3  2  9       9       2       7
4  4  4  3       7       8       9
5  1  5  6       3       9       8
6  2  2  9       6       1       7
7  4  3  2       9       6       8
8  6  7  2       1       1       3
9  6  7  9       4       3       6
```

**as numpy array:**

```
In [30]: df.ix[7, 'INT001':'INT003'].values
Out[30]: array([9, 6, 8])
```

or

```
In [32]: df.ix[7, df.filter(like='INT0').columns].values
Out[32]: array([9, 6, 8])
```

**as pandas data frame:**

```
In [25]: df.ix[7:7, df.filter(like='INT0').columns]
Out[25]:
   INT001  INT002  INT003
7       9       6       8
```

or

```
In [26]: df.ix[df.index==7, df.filter(like='INT0').columns]
Out[26]:
   INT001  INT002  INT003
7       9       6       8
```

or

```
In [28]: df.ix[df.index==7, 'INT001':'INT003']
Out[28]:
   INT001  INT002  INT003
7       9       6       8
```

Setup:

```
df = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randint(1,10,(10,6)), columns=list('abc')+['INT001','INT002','INT003'])
```

Answer (score 1):

I would use a generator to create a list of all the columns you want like

```
    from string import zfill
    import numpy as np

    cols = ['INT0' + zfill(str(i), 2) for i in np.arange(1, 100, 1)]
```

Then you can use pandas .iloc to index by integer location as read in [here](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/version/0.17.0/generated/pandas.DataFrame.iloc.html)

After that you can call .sum() on the array.